# Configure compiled electron application from external file

Tags: angular, electron

Problem:
I need to configure COMPILED Electron application from external file. Config includes API url. When the application starts it should point to this url.

If compare with C# or JAVA I want to have behavior like app.config or application.properties provides.

Questions:
How to implement reading the config file and settings API url at start.
What is standard approach for electron to configure it from external file?

Any information is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

P.S. Electron hosts Angular 7 application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I've added the configuration in following way:

For reading configuration file I used electron-store package.
The configuration read in main thread once per start. I used IPC for passing configuration data from main thread to render thread and cache it in angular service.
That worked for me.